# XEN stop all virtual machine when shutdown

Tags: centos, xen

I am using XEN on CentOS 6.5 64
I want a way to stop all virtual machine when XEN server shutdown
I build service call in stop `xm shutdown -a` but not working

```
#!/bin/bash
# chkconfig: 2345 95 20
# description: 
# processname: 

stop()
{
    /usr/sbin/xm shutdown -a
   while [[ true ]]; do
     if [[ `virsh list|wc -l` == 4 ]]; then
       break
     fi
     sleep 1
   done
}

case "$1" in
  stop)
    stop
    ;;
  *)
    echo $"Usage: $prog {stop}"
esac
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Xen4CentOS I would recommend using [libvirt](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Xen/Xen4QuickStart/Xen4Libvirt). Although it is using a xen driver to interface with `xm` and `xl` and not dedicated interface to the dom0 it will automate things like startup, shutdown, network interfaces and an easy installation interface. The trade-off for using an extra abstraction layer is compensated by having a system that is much closer to the default KVM virtualization which is default in CentOS (and RHEL).

When using libvirt the default shutdown action will be 'suspend' which is not supported by this software combination at this time. Changing `/etc/sysconfig/libvirt-guests` setting `ON_SHUTDOWN=shutdown` will provide a proper shutdown script for the VM's.

Comment: "suspend [...] is not supported by this software combination at this time" Is this still true today with CentOS 7?

Comment: @sauerburger, i'm not sure, but the documentation still states: "Since 0.10.2 it is possible to forcibly enable or disable BIOS advertisements to the guest OS. (NB: Only qemu driver support)", https://libvirt.org/formatdomain.html